# Would a polynomial time solution for an NP complete problem that relies on precomputed primes be sufficient to prove P=NP?

Tags: computer-science, computational-complexity

Suppose one has an algorithm for TSP or any other NP-complete problem. It can run in polynomial time if and only if a list of the first n primes are provided as precomputed. Would that be sufficient to prove P=NP?

My suspicion is no, my hope is yes.

For that matter, is there some algoithm that generates the nth prime deterministically in polynomial time or better, regardless of the size of n or at least up to very large n (10^22 maybe)?

Again, I suspect no.

Comment: Is $n$ a constant or a parameter that's supposed to scale with the size of the TSP input?

Comment: For example, with regard to the subset sum problem, n (in the poor context I've used it for this question) would be defined: $n=P_k$ where $k$ is the size of the set and $P_k$ is a primorial.

Comment: I suspect no, to both questions.

Comment: @GregMartin I'm in good company, then! Thanks.